# Why doesn't the Put method did not send any response in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, postman

I have an API that must using put method but doesn't work. I tried too many ways but none worked.
well, I don't know why doesn't work the Put method or maybe it is my fault. however, the Put method in Postman is correct, I can't fix it in Flutter.

---

Following my code for the send-put method

**My parameters used on the put request**

```
{
    "phone_number": "155556485515", // required
    "full_name": "AMIN AZIZZADEH", // required
    "admin_role": "1", // required| 1 => admin | 2 => operator
    "password": "#edg$#sdghd", // required
    "password_confirmation": "#edg$#sdghd", // required
    "email": "amin@gmail.com", // nullable
    "is_active": "0", // 0 => active | 1 => deactive
    "national_id": "125852", // nullable | shomare shenasname
    "address": "US" // nullable
}
```

**Send method :**

It is just the part of the send that is in my code that doesn't send put method.

```
    Map<String, String> authorization = {};
    Map<String, dynamic> bodyMap = {};

    var uri =
        Uri.parse(config.url);
    var response = await http.put(
      uri,
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader:'Bearer ${config.token}',
        HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
      },
      body: bodyMap,
    );
    print('response boz -> ${response.body}');
```

Log

[image]

I tried with the method, but I could not.

```
var response = await put(
  config.url,
  headers: authorization,
  jsonEncode(
    <String, String>{
"phone_number": "155556485515", 
"full_name": "AMIN AZIZZADEH", 
"admin_role": "1", 
"password": "#edg$#sdghd",
"password_confirmation": "#edg$#sdghd",
"email": "amin@gmail.com",
"is_active": "0",
"national_id": "125852",
"address": "US",
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: The tag [api] description says "DO NOT USE THIS TAG".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decode your response from json to Map, you can use `jsonDecode` for decode your response, look at bellow example,

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  String jsonString = '{"name": "Amin", "age": 25}';
  Map<String, dynamic> decodedMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);

  print(decodedMap['name']); // Output: Amin
  print(decodedMap['age']);  // Output: 25
}
```

this is example for how to use `jsonDecode`.

When we try it with your code we can get bellow updates,

```
var response = await http.put(
  uri,
  headers: {
    HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer ${config.token}',
    HttpHeaders.acceptHeader: 'application/json',
    HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json',
  },
  body: jsonEncode(bodyMap), // Encode bodyMap to JSON format
);
```

so your request sending part is ok as my knowladge,

```
var response = await put(
  config.url,
  headers: authorization,
  jsonEncode(
    <String, String>{
"phone_number": "155556485515", 
"full_name": "AMIN AZIZZADEH", 
"admin_role": "1", 
"password": "#edg$#sdghd",
"password_confirmation": "#edg$#sdghd",
"email": "amin@gmail.com",
"is_active": "0",
"national_id": "125852",
"address": "US",
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: yes I got 200 status code responses but no changed data

Comment: Thanks for the response but I used the post method and sent "_method": "put" with parameters and I got a response of 200 and was changed list.